# Distance service.getdistancematrix is never called ( google maps API )

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to calculate the distance bewteen two locations using the goole maps API.
Everything looks fine to me but getDistanceMatrix's callback is never called.

What's wrong with this code ?

```
function GetNeasetMarker(currentLocation)
{

myOrigin = "Chicago, IL";
myDestination = "Springfield, IL";

var start = new google.maps.LatLng(currentLocation.coords.latitude,currentLocation.coords.longitude);
var distancesArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
{
var end = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);

var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

service.getDistanceMatrix(
                             {
                              origins : start,
                              destinations : end,
                              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                              unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                              avoidHighways: false,
                              avoidTolls: false
                             },


                             function (response, status)
                             {
                              window.alert("Inside callback.");
                              var dvTest = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
                              dvTest.innerHTML += "callback from getDistanceMatrix.<br />";

                              if (status==google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.ok && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS")
                              {
                                var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
                                var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
                                var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
                                    dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
                                    dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
                                    dvDistance.innerHTML += "Duration:" + duration;

                                distancesArray.push(i);
                              } else 
                              {
                                dvTest = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
                                dvTest.innerHTML += " For started, locations length = "+ locations.length +"<br />";

                                window.alert("Aucun chemin trouvé");
                              }
                             }


                         );


}

dvTest = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
dvTest.innerHTML += "The distance list = " + distancesArray.toString() + "<br/>.size = "+distancesArray.length+ "<br />";

var ClosestLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[GetMin(distancesArray)][1], locations[GetMin(distancesArray)][2]);


}
```

Im using dvTest to display the distance it never shows anything as its never called.

Comment: The `origins` and `destinations` properties of the request need to be arrays.  You have logic errors in your code.  What errors do you see in the javascript console?

Comment: @geocodezip I get no errors at all on the console. And about the array part, do u mean text ?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @geocodezip done, i also tried using myOrigin and myDestination it changes nothing.

Comment: What is `myOrigin` and `myDestination`?  Why do you believe using those should change anything?

Comment: You said to use arrays as opposed to latitude and longitude coordinate. Thats what myOrigin and myDestination are for, I tested them and nothing changes.

Comment: Looking at your posted code, those are strings, not arrays.

Comment: Strings are an arrays of characters what kind of arrays did you have in mind?

Comment: Javascript Arrays as described in [the documentation for the DistanceMatrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DistanceMatrixRequest)

Comment: Locations are an array of markers which i use on destinations.

Comment: You didn't provide that data in your question.  And I suspect it is just an array of arrays based on how your code is using it, not of markers or `google.maps.LatLng` objects or of strings containing addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues:

1. The `origins` and `destinations` properties in the [DistanceMatrixRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DistanceMatrixRequest) object must be javascript arrays of either `google.maps.LatLng` objects or strings representing addresses.
2. The call to the DistanceMatrixService is inside the loop on the destinations, you want to use that loop to create the `destinations array, then pass that in to a single call to the DistanceMatrixService.
3. Javascript is case sensitive, in the callback function you are comparing the returned `status` to `google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.ok`, that should be `google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK`.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/eugayrrn/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var locations = [
  ['New York, NY, USA', 40.7127837, -74.0059413, 4],
  ['Newark, NJ, USA', 40.735657, -74.1723667, 5],
  ['Baltimore, MD, USA', 39.2903848, -76.6121893, 3],
  ['Tampa, FL, USA', 27.950575, -82.4571776, 2],
  ['Long Beach, CA, USA', 33.7700504, -118.19373949999999, 1]
];

function initialize() {
  var start = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
  var distancesArray = [];
  var end = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    end.push(new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]));
  }
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix({
      origins: [start],
      destinations: end,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    },
    function(response, status) {
      var dvTest = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
      dvTest.innerHTML += "getDistanceMatrix's callback.<br />";

      if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.rows.length; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j < response.rows[i].elements.length; j++) {
            var distance = response.rows[i].elements[j].distance.text;
            var duration = response.rows[i].elements[j].duration.text;
            var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
            dvDistance.innerHTML += "[" + j + "] Distance: " + distance;
            dvDistance.innerHTML += " Duration:" + duration + "<br />";
          }
        }
      } else {
        dvTest = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
        dvTest.innerHTML += " For started, locations length = " + locations.length + "<br />";
      }
    }


  );
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="dvDistance"></div>
```